# How can I find daemon type elite creatures in Inquisitor: Martyr / Prophecy

Tags: warhammer-40k-inquisitor-martyr

I'm trying to unlock a couple of Ancient Relics with my level 80 tech priest inquisitor, and I need to kill daemon type elite creatures. Unfortunately, all the missions that can spawn chaos daemons seem to be spawning a bunch of hordes, regulars and champions, but all the daemon hosts seem to be boss-level, and all the elite are always chaos engines. Alas, none of those count.

Comment: What kind of missions are you doing? Any Khorne or Nurgle random mission (maybe Hunt) should have what you are looking for.

Comment: I've done a ton of both. I've actually seen one daemon elite in a Tainted Rebel Guard mission, unexpectedly... I know Aeldari and Drukhari don't have them, but everything else seems to have the same incredibly small chance of spawning one...

Comment: Try void crusades, [this Steam thread](https://steamcommunity.com/app/527430/discussions/0/1630790987584765892/) suggests that you can get 10+ each one.

Comment: Been doing those a lot as well. No such luck...

Comment: Maybe the shards used affect the type of enemies?

Comment: The shards used, you mean the void shards? Yea, each crusade is a set sequence of maps, mission types and enemies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Farm Amber Void crusade, 2nd mission - Bonus "Intel Pursuit" in the lower part has 1 such elite.

---

**Longer Version**

In theory, you should run any random Nurgle missions. Hunts and Assassinations should have 3 elites or 2 elites and 1 boss.

But the problem is that for some reason most of Nurgle elites don't have a "Daemon" tag, for example both Nurgle Dreadnought and Nurgle Hellbrute are elites and chaos engines, but not daemons:

[image: Dreadnought]

[image: Hellbrute]

So looks like we only need this guy, Giant Chaos Spawn:

[image: Giant Chaos Spawn]

Most of the missions in the game are randomly generated, except for Campaign (which you can't replay), some special modes - like Unholy Cathedral (which doesn't have any Chaos Spawns) and Void Crusades. Likely for us, I found a single Void Crusade mission not far from the beginning with 1 Giant Chaos Spawn in it. It's Amber Void Crusade, Bonus "Intel Pursuit", I marked it on this screenshot:

[image]

Comment: This was a while ago, and it was a seasonal requirement :), but I'm accepting anyway, as it's a good answer, and may become useful again.